# How can I make wifi work after suspending, Ubuntu 9.04 on Lenovo T61

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, wireless-networking

After resuming from suspended state, my wifi seems to never be able to reconnect to networks. It keeps searching and trying to connect, but then fails. The list of networks never seems to update either.

This is Ubuntu 9.04, on a Lenovo T61 with Atheros 802.11b/g card.

My last resort has been to reload the kernel driver after resuming and then run:

```
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager restart
```

...but this is less than *ideal* ;-)

Comment: Are you using ndiswrapper? If so, I'd recommend switching to madwifi.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with NetworkManager under Ubuntu 9.04 on my Dell laptop -- I wound up replacing it with WICD following [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) at Ubuntu's site.   Your mileage will likely vary, et cetera, blah blah.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem not only for Ubuntu but also for Windows.  I've found that on many computers (Windows or Linux) this is a problem.  Not sure why though...

-JFV

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, and don't quote me on this, but its probably related to Atheros.  I've had limited problems on machines I've used w/intel networking.

I currently use a T61 w/intel wireless N (4965 i believe) with no problems at any time with any OS, whether it be after boot, or after lid/suspend/hibernate resume.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade from some form of Ubuntu 8? Did you need to do some tricks to get WiFi to work in Ubuntu 8?

My Dell laptop upgraded from Ubuntu 8.10 to 9.04 without a problem. The original install had also been painless. On my Thinkpads, I had more problems with the ubuntu 8.10 installs and need to do some configuration tweaking. Upgrading didn't quite work, but the clean install was very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a more specific workaround that can be better automated, you need to pinpoint exactly what is failing.

My best guess at the moment is that your driver doesn't like being suspended, and does something funky instead of quietly bringing the interface down.  I'd try to bring the wireless interface down manually (cnetworkmanager -w false) before suspending, then bringing it up manually afterwards (cnetworkmanager -w true). (note, you can also use the networkmanager applet to do this).  If this solves your problem, you can stick those commands into your suspend/resume scripts, wherever they happen to be in your distro (I'm guessing somewhere in /etc, but I'm not at all sure).